# Is the power series ring over a polynomial ring the same as the polynomial ring over the power series ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, power-series

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1.$ Then consider the power series ring over a polynomial ring as $R[X][[Y]]$ and the polynomial ring over a power series ring $R[[Y]][X].$ Are these two objects  same ?

I think $R[X][[Y]] \subset R[[Y]][X].$ Is the converse also true ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inclusions $R[X][[Y]] \subset R[[X]][Y]$ or $R[X][[Y]] \subset R[[Y]][X]$ are **false**.

Consider the sequence $a_k = X^k$ in $R[X]$ and then $\sum_k a_k Y^k = \sum X^k Y^k \in R[X][[Y]]$. This formal power series is not in $R[[Y]][X]$ and not in $R[[X]][Y]$.

On the other hand $R[[X]][Y] \subset R[Y][[X]]$, by rearranging terms.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer.